# Do notation in haskell

Tags: haskell

So I am trying to program a function in haskell which does the following things:
1. Input is a string 
2. function first removes all letters of the string and only numbers remain
3. function converts the string numbers to int numbers
4. function sums the numbers in the string together and prints it out

My Code til' Step #3

```
func str = 
    do 
    str <- filter (< 'a') str
    str2 <- map digitToInt str
    return str2
```

somehow this doesn't work if I remove the 4th line with map digitToInt it works til step #2 fine but I dont know what the problem here is

The Error is an couldnt match expected type [Char] with actual type Char

Thank you in advance

Comment: example input "45abc" output 9

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want `do` notation at all, just normal variable binding. So:

```
func str = str2 where
    str1 = filter (<'a') str
    str2 = map digitToInt str1
```

Tracking the most recently used name is annoying, isn't it? Plus it's easy to make a mistake and type `str` instead of `str1` somewhere, or similar. Enter function composition:

```
func str = str2 where
    str2 = (map digitToInt . filter (<'a')) str
```

In fact, I would inline the definition of `str2`, then elide `str` entirely:

```
func = map digitToInt . filter (<'a')
```

I would prefer to use `isDigit` over `(<'a')`; we can toss in a sum at the same time.

```
func = sum . map digitToInt . filter isDigit
```

Reads nice and clean, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

You *could* use `do` notation, since strings are lists and lists are monads. It would look like this, though:

```
func :: String -> [Int]
func str = do
  c <- filter (< 'a') str  -- Get one character
  return (digitToInt c)    -- Change that character to a integer
```

What is the value of `c`? It's not just one character, but *all* of them. The list monad models nondeterminism. Imagine that `func` makes multiple copies of itself, with each copy selecting a different character `c` from the input string. `return` makes a new list from the result, and the monad takes care of glue the individual lists into a one final list. It's a little clearer if you compare it its deconstructed form.

```
func str = filter (< 'a') str >>= \c -> return (digitToInt c)
```

Since `xs >>= f = concatMap f xs` and `return x = [x]` in the `Monad []` instance, it becomes:

```
func str = concatMap (\c -> [digitToInt c]) (filter (< 'a') str)
```

However, the monadic form isn't necessary, as your function only needs to make use of the `Functor` instance of `[]`, since every element from the first list corresponds to exactly one element in the final list:

```
-- Or in a form closer to Daniel Wagner's answer
func str = fmap digitToInt (filter (< 'a') str)
```

Comment: Yeah. I think this should go with a big warning up front though that such use of `do` notation behaves completely different from what one might expect in an imperative language.

Comment: @leftaroundabout that wouldn't be an issue at all if "`do`" were named "`for`" in the first place (`for s in getString: print s`, `for s2 in (for s in getString: yield (s++"!")): print s2`, `for c in "string": [c,c]`). spilled milk, yes.

Comment: @WillNess seriously? That syntax looks nowhere near as good as the current `do` syntax. `yield` instead of `return` would of course be preferrable (that one would actually be quite easy to change), but `for` seems a worse choice of keyword than for most monads, more misleading than `do`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I don't see a problem there. but it could also be `with s from getString:`, `with c from "string":` etc.